# Create alerts in Azure application insights web test using Terraform

Tags: terraform

I wonder if it's possible to add alert rule to Azure application insights web test using terraform

[image]

In terraform documentation I don't see such an option: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/application_insights_web_test.html

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `azurerm_monitor_metric_alert` resource.

[Terraform example is here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/monitor_metric_alert.html)

Comment: I think it was added later on :) Thanks